# accessing your app saved files and be able to view it through your app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, storage

Good day people. I'd just like to ask if its possible to view my saved files (i.e audio or text files) from my device's external storage, which is where I wanted my recorded speech to be saved into, through my app? Like when I press a button (i.e button to access your app's gallery), it will let you to access your app's directory and be able to see the saved files in there. I'm new to android development, and I use android studio for developing hence I'm in need of your help. Thank you in advanced.